# Loop through all controls of a Form, even those in GroupBoxes

Tags: c#, groupbox

I'd like to add an event to all TextBoxes on my `Form`:

```
foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
{
    if (C.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox))
    {
        C.TextChanged += new EventHandler(C_TextChanged);
    }
}
```

The problem is that they are stored in several GroupBoxes and my loop doesn't see them. I could loop through controls of each `GroupBox` individually but is it possible to do it all  in a simple way  in one loop?

Comment: You can do it in a recursive loop.

Comment: I have made an [API Proposal: Add Descendants property for Control](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/5195) for this. If you like it, please upvote it on github.com/dotnet/winforms.

Answer (score 40):

The `Controls` collection of Forms and container controls contains only the immediate children. In order to get all the controls, you need to traverse the controls tree and to apply this operation recursively

```
private void AddTextChangedHandler(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) {
            c.TextChanged += new EventHandler(C_TextChanged);
        } else {
            AddTextChangedHandler(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The form derives (indirectly) from `Control` as well and all controls have a `Controls` collection. So you can call the method like this in your form:

```
AddTextChangedHandler(this);
```

---

A more general solution would be to create an extension method that applies an action recursively to all controls. In a static class (e.g. `WinFormsExtensions`) add this method:

```
public static void ForAllControls(this Control parent, Action<Control> action)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls) {
        action(c);
        ForAllControls(c, action);
    }
}
```

The static classes namespace must be "visible", i.e., add an appropriate `using` declaration if it is in another namespace.

Then you can call it like this, where `this` is the form; you can also replace `this` by a form or control variable whose nested controls have to be affected:

```
this.ForAllControls(c =>
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)) {
        c.TextChanged += C_TextChanged;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 22):

A few simple, general purpose tools make this problem very straightforward.  We can create a simple method that will traverse an entire control's tree, returning a sequence of all of it's children, all of their children, and so on, covering all controls, not just to a fixed depth.  We could use recursion, but by avoiding recursion it will perform better.

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllChildren(this Control root)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
            stack.Push(child);
        yield return next;
    }
}
```

Using this we can get all of the children, filter out those of the type we need, and then attach the handler *very* easily:

```
foreach(var textbox in GetAllChildren().OfType<Textbox>())
    textbox.TextChanged += C_TextChanged;
```

Comment: I did not know that there was an alternative solution to recursion. Always learning.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
AllSubControls(this).OfType<TextBox>().ToList()
    .ForEach(o => o.TextChanged += C_TextChanged);
```

where AllSubControls is

```
private static IEnumerable<Control> AllSubControls(Control control)
    => Enumerable.Repeat(control, 1)
       .Union(control.Controls.OfType<Control>()
                              .SelectMany(AllSubControls)
             );
```

LINQ is great!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an older topic, but would say the code snippet from http://backstreet.ch/coding/code-snippets/mit-c-rekursiv-durch-form-controls-loopen/ is a clever solution for this problem.

It uses an extension method for ControlCollection.

```
public static void ApplyToAll<T>(this Control.ControlCollection controlCollection, string tagFilter, Action action)
{
    foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagFilter))
        {
            if (control.Tag == null)
            {
                control.Tag = "";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagFilter) && control.Tag.ToString() == tagFilter && control is T)
            {
                action(control);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (control is T)
            {
                action(control);
            }
        }

        if (control.Controls != null && control.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            ApplyToAll(control.Controls, tagFilter, action);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to assign an event to all the TextBox controls you can write a statement like (where 'this' is the form):

```
this.Controls.ApplyToAll<TextBox>("", control =>
{
    control.TextChanged += SomeEvent
});
```

Optionally you can filter the controls by their tags.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen anyone using linq and/or yield so here goes:

```
public static class UtilitiesX {

    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetEntireControlsTree(this Control rootControl)
    {
        yield return rootControl;
        foreach (var childControl in rootControl.Controls.Cast<Control>().SelectMany(x => x.GetEntireControlsTree()))
        {
            yield return childControl;
        }
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var obj in en) action(obj);
    }
}
```

You may then use it to your heart's desire:

```
someControl.GetEntireControlsTree().OfType<TextBox>().ForEach(x => x.Click += someHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated, you will have to go deeper than just cycling over each element in your form. This, unfortunately, implies the use of a nested loop.

In the first loop, cycle through each element. IF the element is of type GroupBox, then you know you'll need to cycle through each element inside the groupbox, before continuing; else add the event as normal.

You seem to have a decent grasp of C# so I won't give you any code; purely to ensure you develop all the important concepts that are involved in problem solving :)

Answer (score 1):

you can only loop through open forms in windows forms using form collection for example to set windows start position for all open forms:

```
public static void setStartPosition()
        {
            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

            foreach(Form f in fc)
            {
                f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Question regarding "Adding an Event to your TextBoxes"; was already answered; I'm providing some explanation and adding an iteration alternative using a for loop instead.

**Problem:**

- Being Unable to Get Controls Inside a Container.

**Solution:**

- In order to retrieve the Controls inside a Container you have to specify the Container that Contains the Controls you wish to access to.
  Therefore your loop must check the Controls inside a Container.

  Otherwise your loop will not find the Controls inside a Container.

**i.e:**

```
foreach (Control control in myContainer.Controls)
{
   if (control is TextBox) { /* Do Something */ }
}
```

- In case you have several Containers:

  Initially iterate the Containers.

   Then iterate over the controls inside the container (the container found in the initial iteration).

**Pseudo Code Example on How to use a for Loop Instead:**

```
    /// <summary> Iterate Controls Inside a Container using a for Loop. </summary>
    public void IterateOverControlsIncontainer()
    {
        // Iterate Controls Inside a Container (i.e: a Panel Container)
        for (int i = 0; i < myContainer.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            // Get Container Control by Current Iteration Index
            // Note:
            // You don't need to dispose or set a variable to null.
            // The ".NET" GabageCollector (GC); will clear up any unreferenced classes when a method ends in it's own time.
            Control control = myContainer.Controls[i];

            // Perform your Comparison
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                // Control Iteration Test.
                // Shall Display a MessageBox for Each Matching Control in Specified Container.
                MessageBox.Show("Control Name: " + control.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Good Job!

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

I needed to disable all the controls in a form, including groupboxes. This code worked:

```
    private void AlterControlsEnable(bool ControlEnabled)
    {
        foreach (Control i in Controls)
            i.Enabled = ControlEnabled;
    }
```