# make a tab from a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I'm having problems. I get a lot of errors and this is annoying me when I'm trying to add tabs from a user control.
Here is the code

```
public Form1 f1 { get; private set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabPage tp = new TabPage { };
    tp.Text = "NewTab";
    tp.Controls.Add(new b());
    f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);  //>>> errors here
}
```

[Image for more details: code no showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkRAz.png)

[Run-time errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SG40.png)

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, but we can't read in your mind or direct from your screeen... You have to provide more details about your issues, if you want our help.

Comment: In your Windows Forms Designer, make `tabControl1` access modifier public in `Form1`  It's an option in the property list.

Comment: Did you set `f1` to the form object ? For example if the above code is inside the class `Foo`, did you call it from within the instance of `Form1` like this `Foo.f1 = this;` or `Foo.f1 = new Form1();`.  If you do not tell the program what instance of `Form1` is to be used for `f1` by assigning it, it will give you a null exception since no instance of `Form1` has been assigned to `f1`.

Answer (score 6):

Your code isn't assigning `f1` which is why you are getting a null reference exception at run time.

Depending on the architecture of your project ...

A. If `UserControl` is instantiated in the parent `Form` code behind then simply inject `f1` into the constructor of the `UserControl`:

```
private readonly MyForm _f1;

public b(MyForm f1){
    InitializeComponents();

    _f1 = f1;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TabPage tp = new TabPage { };
    tp.Text = "NewTab";
    tp.Controls.Add(new b());

    //  assumes 'tabControl1' exists as a publicly accessible control
    _f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
}
```

B. If using [M-V-P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) then, using the code you have, the Presenter can assign the `f1` variable at initialization but make the setter `public` or `internal`.

Comment: Does not work, since `f1` is typed as `Form` and not `MyForm` (or whatever). There is no `Form.tabControl1`.

Answer (score 0):

`f1` is null because no form has been assigned to it. Drop this property and instead write:

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage { };
tp.Text = "NewTab";
tp.Controls.Add(new b());
FindForm().Controls.OfType<TabControl>().Single().TabPages.Add(tp);
```

This assumes that the form contains exactly one TabControl and that it is a top level control. If it can be inside another container control, you will have to loop the controls recursively. This question might help: [Loop through all controls on a form, even those in groupboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15186828/880990)

Note, that your approach has yet another issue: `f1` is typed as `Form`, but this general type has no `tabControl1`. You would have to type it with a specific form type `MyForm f { get; set; }`.

---

Maybe an easier way to access the TabControl is to let the form implement an interface defining just a property returning this TabControl:

```
public interface ITabControlProvider
{
    TabControl MainTabControl { get; }
}
```

Then let your form implement it

```
public partial class MyForm : Form, ITabControlProvider
{
    ...

    TabControl MainTabControl { get { return tabControl1; } }
}
```

Now your UserControl can find the TabControl like this

```
var frm = FindForm() as ITabControlProvider;
if (frm != null) {
    frm.MainTabControl.TabPages.Add(tp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this code looks like it is all happening from inside a form, you can try this :

```
public Form1 f1 { get; private set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(f1 == null) { f1 = this; }
    TabPage tp = new TabPage { };
    tp.Text = "NewTab";
    tp.Controls.Add(new b());
    f1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);  //>>> errors here
}
```

If it is happening inside a `UserControl`, then you can try this :

```
public Foo : UserControl {

    public TabControl tabControl { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tabControl == null) {
            // do nothing - ignore button click.
        } else {
            TabPage tp = new TabPage { };
            tp.Text = "NewTab";
            tp.Controls.Add(new b());
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tp);  //>>> errors here
        }
    }
}
```

The on the form you have this user control added to, you can either choose the TabControl it is bound to from the drop-down menu in the property editor, or you can assign it in code like this :

```
foo1.tabControl = tabControl1;
```

Comment: ermmmm no and I was wondering is there a tabcontrol for a webbrowser like firefox with add tab buttons and remove tab buttons