# Exclude control container from list

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

If I have a form with this container for example:

```
+---------------------------------panel 1----+
|                                            |
|   +------------------panel 2---+           |
|   |                            |           |
|   | textbox1                   |           |
|   | combobox1        checkBox1 |           |
|   +----------------------------+           |
|                                            |
|   +------------tableLayoutPanel1-+         |
|   |                              |         |
|   | textbox2                     |         |
|   +------------------------------+         |
|                                            |
|   +-------------FlowLayoutPanel1-+         |
|   |textbox3  Combobox2           |         |
|   +------------------------------+         |
|                                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

I already have a function for getting all controls of a certain type from a given container (with a recursive call to get even controls contained) :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindAllChildrenByType<T>(this Control control)
    {
        IEnumerable<Control> controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls
            .OfType<T>()
            .Concat<T>(controls.SelectMany<Control, T>(ctrl => FindAllChildrenByType<T>(ctrl)));
    }
```

This works fine (here it returns textbox1, combobox1, checkbox1, textbox2, textbox3, combobox2)

Now, I want a new function with a similar behavior : get all controls from a container but which are not included in a certain type of container.
In my example the function could return all controls contained in panel1 which are never contained in a tableLayoutPanel (here textbox1, combobox1, checkbox1, textbox3, combobox2).

I've tried :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindAllChildrenByType<T>(this Control control)
    {
        IEnumerable<Control> controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls
            .OfType<T>()
            .Concat<T>(controls .Where(ctrl => ctrl.GetType() != typeof(TableLayoutPanel))
                                .SelectMany<Control, T>(ctrl => FindAllChildrenByType<T>(ctrl))
                        );
    }
```

And :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindAllChildrenByType2<T>(this Control control)
    {
        IEnumerable<Control> controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        return controls
            .OfType<T>()
            .Concat<T>(controls.SelectMany<Control, T>(ctrl => FindAllChildrenByType<T>(ctrl)))
            .Where<T>(ctrl => ctrl.GetType() != typeof(TableLayoutPanel));
    }
```

with the same result : I get a list of all controls even those which must have been excluded (textBox2 in the TableLayoutPanel in the example).

Any idea of where I got lost?

Comment: What's the issue with what you've tried?

Comment: I get all the controls even those in the tableLayoutPanel.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. `.Concat<T>(controls .Where(ctrl => ctrl.GetType() != typeof(TableLayoutPanel))
                                .SelectMany<Control, T>(ctrl => FindAllChildrenByType<T>(ctrl))
                        );` seems to exclude the textbox2 as you desire. How do you call this? Please see my [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ihVf4w)

Comment: In fact i've created an example to illustrate my issue and i've not tried to execute the program with it. In real, i use the function with a user control to initialize certain properties of contained controls and i've investigate the enumeration returned by the call to see that supposed ignored controls were added to the list. I suppose the bug is hidding elsewhere and i will search deeper...

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20124683/861716) that uses a non-recursive method to traverse a tree structure I came up with this method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls<TControl>(this Control root, 
    Type excludedContainer = null)
        where TControl : Control
{
    var queue = new Queue<Control>();
    queue.Enqueue(root);

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var next = queue.Dequeue();
        
        if (!next.GetType().Equals(excludedContainer))
        foreach (Control child in next.Controls)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
        if (!next.HasChildren && next is TControl typed)
        {
            yield return typed;
        }
    }
}
```

Non-recursive methods are always preferred because they won't exhaust the call stack (although in this case that wouldn't be likely anyway).

It does essentially the same thing as the original: collect controls level-by-level in a `while` loop. I only replaced `Stack` by `Queue` so the controls are returned from top to bottom. And of course added the conditions you were looking for: filtered type and excluded container type.