# How to iterate over windows forms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have 5 textboxes with 5 labels,named like this:

- `text1`, `text2`, `text3`, etc.
- `label1`, `label2`, `label3`, etc.

What I want to do is to target each of them and apply the same code, without having to write something individually. I was thinking about a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        tcpCLient.ConnectAsync(text(i).Text, 80);
        label(i).Text = "Online";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        label(i).Text = "Offline";
    }
}
```

The problem is that Visual Studio won't let me compile as *"The name 'text' does not exist in the current context"*.

Is this the wrong approach? How would you do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: it's web app or desktop , mvc, winforms what ?

Comment: _Guessing_ it is winforms, the form has a Property you can iterate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.8 but I'd actually recommend to use a Model, Controller and Binding.

Comment: By the way, that code won't work anyway. You are trying to connect one instance of TcpClient to 4 Endpoints??

Comment: May I ask if you are coming from a VB or JavaScript background? Makes it easier to "speak your language" ...

Comment: If you want to dig into Binding, you can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding

Comment: It is a desktop WinForms in C# with Framework 4.8. I solved this using Clint's method but I will look into Binding as @Fildor suggested!
It seems to work like this too as long as I close the TCP after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The name 'text' does not exist in the current context".
>
> ***text[i].Text*  you can only do this if `text` type implements `IEnumerable`**

You can do this to enumerate over your controls

```
var labels = new List<Label> { label1, label2, label3};
var textBoxs = new List<TextBox> { text1, text2, text3};


for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        tcpCLient.ConnectAsync(textBoxs[i].Text, 80);
        labels[i].Text = "Online";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        labels[i].Text = "Offline";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick. I will keep in mind the fact that enumeration work only with arrays.

Comment: "the fact that enumeration work only with arrays" - it is incorrect statement. any class can implement indexer. not to mention that `List` != array

Comment: `labels(i)` is incorrect syntax for access by index. it should be `labels[i]`

Comment: @ASh, good catch, edited

Answer (score 2):

Well, the code `label(i).Text` is not well-formed. That seems like you are trying to call a function `label` with parameter `i` and access the member `Text` of such result.

You could do something like this

```
Label[] labels = { label1, label2, label3, label4, label5 };
TextBox[] textBoxes = { text1, text2, text3, text4, text5 };

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        tcpCLient.ConnectAsync(textBoxes[i].Text, 80);
        labels[i].Text = "Online";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        labels[i].Text = "Offline";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate a Form's `Controls` through its `ControlCollection`.

See [Form.ControlCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.controlcollection?view=netframework-4.8).

But mind that this includes *all* controls. If you want to pick specific ones, you'd have to filter by type and/or name.

That out of the way, I'd strongly advise to go a different route, though. I'd make a `UserControl` and make use of the MVC pattern in conjunction with [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding).

Also mind, that your code won't work as expected, since it seems to try to connect the same instance of `TcpClient` to 4 different Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

In windows forms you can iterate over the `Forms.Controls` to get all the labels and textboxes in a more automated way.

Example:

```cs
List<TextBox> textBoxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("text"))
    .ToList();

List<Label> labels = Controls.OfType<Label>()
    .Where(lbl => lbl.Name.StartsWith("label"))
    .ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        tcpCLient.ConnectAsync(text(i).Text, 80);
        labels[i].Text = "Online";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        textBoxes[i].Text = "Offline";
    }
}
```

**Note**: This way you can only get the **immediate children** of the `Form`. If the textboxes and labels are children of a different parent control (e.g. `Panel`), you will need to iterate over the `Controls` property of that parent control. To iterate over **all** the control of a `Form` see: [Loop through all controls on a form,even those in groupboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186828/loop-through-all-controls-on-a-form-even-those-in-groupboxes)